# problem while installing tenserflow on EC2 machine the process gets killed

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-ec2

Whenever I try to install tenserflow on my free tier eligible ec2 machine on AWS it downloads and then the further process gets killed I tried many things but didn't get any solution for the same[as you can see the tenserflow has been downloaded and then there is a keyword "killed" and the process exits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxw1Z.png)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution there were multiple factors one of them was configuration of machine didn't support Tensorflow thats the reason the job waas getting cancelled .